# Delete multi-line pattern starting on first line of file only

Tags: regex, bash, sed

From a Bash script, I'm trying to delete a pattern from a file like the following:

```
<%
delete this tag
%><? keep this tag ?>
<% keep this tag %>
```

But only if that tag is at the beginning of the file, so the following would be untouched:

```
text to keep
<%
don't delete me now
%>
```

I've tried to piece something together from answers on other questions, but haven't been able to come up with a command that will work like this.

Is this possible with `sed`? Is there a different tool that would work better?

Comment: Can you show us an actual example of your file, to get more insight?

Comment: please add whatever command you tried... it would show your effort... is perl okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after posting, I figured out how to do this in `sed` with the following command:

`sed -e '/<%/{1!b;:x;$!N;/%>/!bx;s/<%.*%>//}' -i "file"`

An explanation of the command:

```
sed -e
    '/<%/           # When we match the start pattern, '<%', execute the following command block
    {
        1!b;        # If we're not on the first line when we match the start pattern, exit
        :x;         # Define label 'x'
        $!N;        # If not at the end of file, capture the current line
        /%>/!bx;    # If we're not at the end pattern, '%>', go to label 'x'
        s/<%.*%>//  # After reaching the end pattern, replace all matching text in the captured lines with nothing
    }'
    -i "file"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to give `perl` a chance then this should work:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/^\s*<%.*?%>//s' file

<? keep this tag ?>
<% keep this tag %>
```

**Breakup:**

- `-0777` : slurp mode to match all the file text including newlines
- `^\s*`: Match start followed by 0 or more white-spaces
- `<%.*?%>`: Match your tag (lazy)

To save changes back to file:

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/^\s*<%.*?%>//s' file
```

Comment: Thanks! This does work, but I managed to find a solution using `sed`. I only went with that for consistency with other commands in the same script.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==1 && /</ { d=1 }     # if < on the first line raise the del flag
d==1 {                   # if del flag up
    if(/>/)              # lower del flag at >
        d=0              
    sub(/<?[^>]+>?/,"")  # replace from < to > with nuthin
} 
/./                      # print nonempty lines
' file
<? keep this tag ?>
<% keep this tag %>
```

The other file processed:

```
text to keep
<%
don't delete me now
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sed`, like:

```
sed '0,/REGEXP/' your_input_file
```

where REGEXP is your desired regular expression.